# Problem with style validation in geoserver

Tags: styles, geoserver

Try to set a style in geoserver styles editor.
but the validation fails

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<StyledLayerDescriptor version="1.0.0"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/sld http://schemas.opengis.net/sld/1.1.0/StyledLayerDescriptor.xsd" xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/sld"
  xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <NamedLayer>
    <Name>capitals</Name>
    <UserStyle>
      <Name>fix_histogram</Name>
      <Title>Fix Histogram</Title>
      <FeatureTypeStyle>
        <Rule>
          <Title>Capitals</Title>
          <RasterSymbolizer>
            <ContrastEnhancement>
                <Normalize>
                 <VendorOption name="algorithm">StretchToMinimumMaximum</VendorOption>
                 <VendorOption name="minValue">50</VendorOption>
                 <VendorOption name="maxValue">100</VendorOption>
                </Normalize>
            </ContrastEnhancement>
          </RasterSymbolizer>                    
        </Rule>
      </FeatureTypeStyle>
    </UserStyle>
  </NamedLayer>
</StyledLayerDescriptor>
```

line 19: cvc-complex-type.2.1: Element 'Normalize' must have no character or element information item [children], because the type's content type is empty.

but this code was taken from the example for RasterSymbolizer:

https://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/styling/sld/reference/rastersymbolizer.html

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that the schema that the editor is using has not been updated to recognise the vendor options you are using.

Does the style work if you apply it?

Comment: I am using the  xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/sld http://schemas.opengis.net/sld/1.1.0/StyledLayerDescriptor.xsd" xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/sld"
  xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">

And validation is done using the geoserver's style editor (by clicking the validation button).

Comment: the code was updated in https://osgeo-org.atlassian.net/browse/GEOT-5180 but I can't recall making a change to the GeoServer validation code. Feel free to make a ticket and pull request if this really bothers you.